# How to find the name of an object created in a class in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, class

So what I need to do, is get the name of a class when its created.

```
class Car {
  constructor(color) {
    this.color = color;
  }
}

newcar = new Car('Red');

objectNames = []
```

I need to get the name of the object I created, (newcar), into the array, (objectNames). I've tried to search it but I'm not even exactly sure what to search for. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What do you mean by "name of the object"? Do you mean "I want to keep track of all the Car objects that are created?"

Comment: yep! sorry if I made it unclear

Answer (score -1, accepted):

do you mean something like this

```js
    objectNames = []
class Car {
  constructor(carmaker,color) {
    this.color = color;
    this.carmaker=carmaker
  }
  saveob(){
    objectNames.push({[this.carmaker]:this.color})
  }
}
newcar = new Car('toyota','Red').saveob()
console.log(objectNames)
console.log(Object.keys(objectNames[0])[0])
console.log(objectNames[0].toyota)
```

Comment: I'm opting for a solution where I don't have to directly input the name to save it

Comment: I have updated the code check it and see if that is what you want

Comment: you can save the object with the properties using the `saveob()` function however if you want to save the who object your just change `this.color` with `this `

Answer (score -1):

Using a getter inside the class

```js
class Car {
  constructor(color) {
    this._color = color;
  }
  get color(){
    return this._color;
  }
}

var newcar = new Car('Red');

var objectNames = [];
objectNames.push(newcar.color);

console.log(objectNames);
```